# No matter what I try to do, I cannot get anaconda navigator to run on windows 10

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

When I try to open anaconda navigator my cmd prompt flashes open with some text and immedietly terminates.

Please help me figure this out... Thanks.

I've tried fresh installs and different directories.

I've tried opening through the shortcut, command prompt, and through the script file.

I've tried all the command prompt commands that I've found on SOF and through github and many help forums. I really cannot figure this out and it's making me want to smash my head through dry wall.

```
(base) C:\Users\itsat>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 30, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 23, in <module>
    import binstar_client
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .mixins.channels import ChannelsMixin
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\mixins\channels.py", line 7, in <module>
    from binstar_client.utils import jencode
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .config import (get_server_api, dirs, load_token, store_token,
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\config.py", line 90, in <module>
    USER_LOGDIR = dirs.user_log_dir
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\appdirs.py", line 253, in user_log_dir
    return user_log_dir(self.appname, self.appauthor, version=self.version)
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\appdirs.py", line 192, in user_log_dir
    path = user_data_dir(appname, appauthor, version)
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\appdirs.py", line 68, in user_data_dir
    path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
  File "C:\Users\itsat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\utils\appdirs.py", line 280, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
    from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.

(base) C:\Users\itsat>
```

Comment: pip install pywin32==300 worked

Answer (score 1):

pip install pywin32==300 fixed the issues.